# Need Explanation: Organization with Objects in a Contact List (Javascript, Codecademy)

Tags: javascript

I've been having some trouble making sense of two javascript functions in this [contact list project](http://bit.ly/Zroroe) on [codecademy](http://bit.ly/Zroroe).

Specifically, I got confused with conditions like, "obj" or "prop". 
I would really appreciate it if someone can explain in detail how these functions work.

Here is the code & thank you:

```
var friends = {};
friends.bill = {
  firstName: "Bill",
  lastName: "Gates",
  number: "(206) 555-5555",
  address: ['One Microsoft Way','Redmond','WA','98052']
};
friends.steve = {
  firstName: "Steve",
  lastName: "Jobs",
  number: "(408) 555-5555",
  address: ['1 Infinite Loop','Cupertino','CA','95014']
};

var list = function(obj) {
  for(var prop in obj) {
    console.log(prop);
  }
};

var search = function(name) {
  for(var prop in friends) {
    if(friends[prop].firstName === name) {
      console.log(friends[prop]);
      return friends[prop];
    }
  }
};

list(friends);
search("Steve");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`obj` is just the name of the parameter of the `list` function that you are creating.  It has no special meaning.  You could call it `foo` or `object`, or anything else that makes sense to you.  The value of the argument you pass to the function call of list (above, namely `friends`) is stored in the parameter in the scope of the function.  That is to say, `obj` essentially becomes `friends` while operating inside the code of `list`.

`prop` is similar: it's just a variable that is created as part of JavaScript's [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) syntax.  `for in` loops over the property names of the object that is the argument to the `in` construct and stores them one by one in `prop`.  Again, you could call this whatever you wanted:

```
var list = function (foo) {
    for (var bar in foo) {
```

However, as I'm sure you've learned, it makes sense to give variable names some meaning, so `obj` is short for "object" as the `list` function operates on any general object, and `prop` is short for "property."

Keep in mind that `for...in` loops over property *names*.  To access the correspoding value, you should use:

```
if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    //access via obj[prop];
}
```

The `search` function actually does this, but without the recommended [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) check.

Comment: You're explanation of the `for (var prop in obj) {` syntax is really helpful. Basically, the `for...in` loop will always deal with property names and an object. 

In the case of `list(friends)`, I can pass in an object, `friends`, it will give me property names, `bill` and `steve`.

But can you clarify the **if** statement in the `search` function i provided? 

`if(friends[prop].firstName === name)` 

I can see that the `search` function will only take `firstName` values of `"Steve"` or `"Bill"`. **But I don't know why that `[prop]` code is in the if condition statement**.

Comment: If you see my explanation on how to access property values, you will see `friends[prop]` is equivalent to `frieds['steve']` (or `friends.steve`) and `.bill`.  `friends['steve'].firstName` is `"Steve"`, so it's used in the comparison to the `name` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

obj is a parameter passed in `list` function. for iterated through names of that obj. For example:

```
var a = {x:5}

for(var prop in a){
    //here prop will be 'x' and a[prop] will be 5 (a['x'] is 5)
    //same goes again for objects that have multiple properties
}
```

In your case:

```
var list = function(obj) {
  for(var prop in obj) {
    console.log(prop); // here will be logged Bill and Steve, because they are properties of friends -object
  }
};
```